# Excel VBA - Unable to select multiple non contiguos column ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a few non-contiguous columns (say Column A, Column C, Column E) into a dynamic array. However, it appears that only contiguous ranges were copied, leaving the non-contiguous ranges, when using the VBA `Application.Union` method.

I have tried copying contiguous columns (A, B, C, D, E), which worked as expected, but non-contiguous columns (A, C, E) doesn't.

Can anyone assist me on this? Thanks.

```
Sub TestFunction()

    Dim TempArray() As Variant
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        Set rngUnion = Application.Union(.Range("A1:A10"), .Range("C1:C10"), .Range("E1:E10"))
    End With

    TempArray = rngUnion
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Hide-ing` the columns you want to skip ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I've tried hiding the columns as well. But, it didn't work.

Comment: You can only use contiguous rectangular ranges when getting the value as a 2-d array.  If you want to do this you will need to build the array from the individual areas.

Comment: It's not possible as this is one of the properties that uses only the first `Area` in the Range. Others are `.Count`, `.Value`, `.Value2`, `.Formula`, etc.

Comment: @TimWilliams If I filter rows and copy and paste on another sheet, the hidden stuff gets skipped.............why doesn't this work with columns ??

Comment: I don't know why - that would be a question for the developers

Comment: AFAIK the co-founder and CEO of StackOverflow designed Excel Basic, so maybe he knows why :] My guess is because non-contiguous range can't always return a rectangular array as each area can have different number of cells.

Comment: If I had to guess it would be that there's no way to infer the *intent* of the user when creating a 2-D array from non-contiguous ranges: if I select two rectangular ranges there's no way to be sure i mean for them to be "side by side" in the resulting array vs. "top to bottom" (eg two 4x4 ranges >> one 4x8 array, or one 8x4 array?)

Comment: @Slai Thanks for the explanation. I get your point.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks to you, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams already answered your question.  I just wanted to demonstrate a cool way to create an array from multiple non-contiguous ranges.  The key to this working is that all the ranges have 1 column and the same number of rows.

`getArrayFromRanges` takes the array of values from each range passed to it and converts it from a 2D array to an 1D array using Transpose.  Each one of these 1D Temp arrays are added to the 1D Data array.  Transpose is then used to convert the Data from an 1D Array od 1D arrays into a 2D array.

```
Sub TestFunction()
    Dim Data
    With Worksheets(2)
        Data = getArrayFromRanges(.Range("A1:A10"), .Range("C1:C10"), .Range("E1:E10"))
        .Range("A12").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
    End With
End Sub

Function getArrayFromRanges(ParamArray Sources())
    Dim Data, Temp, v
    Dim x As Long
    ReDim Data(UBound(Sources))

    For Each v In Sources
        Temp = Application.Transpose(v)
        Data(x) = Temp
        x = x + 1
    Next

    getArrayFromRanges = Application.Transpose(Data)

End Function
```

Sample Data from [Contextures Excel Sample Data](http://www.contextures.com/xlSampleData01.html)

Comment: Hello Thomas. Your solution had worked like charm. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you are doing with the array, so I'm not sure if this will work for you. But, instead of the array, why not use `rngUnion` directly, and loop through its `Areas` collection as needed?

For example, this function:

```
Sub TestFunction2()
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    Dim area As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        Set rngUnion = Application.Union(.Range("A1:A10"), .Range("C1:C10"), .Range("E1:E10"))
    End With

    For Each area In rngUnion.Areas
        Debug.Print area.Address
    Next area

    Set area = Nothing
    Set rngUnion = Nothing
End Sub
```

Returns this output:

```
$A$1:$A$10
$C$1:$C$10
$E$1:$E$10
```

If you really do need the array, you could just use the same loop to add the individual `Areas` (i.e. `Ranges`) to the array.

Comment: My objective is to compare the two multiple ranges from worksheet to other multiple ranges in another worksheet. Based on the comparision ( Say Column 'A' in Sheet1 with Column 'C' in Sheet2, Column 'C' in Sheet1 with Column 'E' in sheet2, Column 'E'  in Sheet1 with Column 'G' in Sheet 2), need to generate report in another worksheet. So, my implementation has to copy the data from different ranges or Areas into an array, So load can be reduced before the comparison is done. I shall try out your suggestion and let u know results. Thank you.